# SSIS Derived Column casting numeric(6,0) to ANSI string drops leading digits

Tags: ssis, data-conversion

I have a package that's reading a table from an Oracle data source. The surrogate key for the table (an identity column) was assigned a numeric(6,0) data type by SSIS.

When I take that column into a Derived Column component and cast it as (DT_STR,100,1252) to store in a lookup table downstream, the string column produces incorrect output - but in a very strange way.

Here's some sample output:

```
ID  ID_AS_STRING
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10   0
11  11
12  12
.
.
20   0
21  21
22  22
.
.
.
30   0
.
.
40   0
```

Basically, it drops the leading digit of the ID if it's divisible by 10 (this goes on into the hundreds and thousands, i.e. 740 becomes 40, 9920 becomes 920.)

Needless to say, this is doubly wrong, since it misses some IDs for the lookup and creates duplicates of others.

If you change the initial column data type to four-bit integer it works fine, so in a way this question is merely academic. But can anyone explain what's going on in SSIS to drop that leading digit of a mod-10 number?

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, the lookup table downstream isn't just a lookup for this ID, it's a lookup on all natural keys within this dataset, which is why the column needs to be a string. This table just happens to have a numeric key.

Comment: tried to recreate, with no joy.  Can you recreate the issue with a small example?